# Listing Directories as a File Tree in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, jqmobi

I am working on a project in Android+PhoneGap+JQM, in which i need to list all the audio files saved inside the SDCARD like a File tree where all the child folders of the root will be listed and when i clicked on any of the child folder subfolders and audio files will be listed(if any) and so on. I tried the jquery file tree mentiond in http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-fileTree/demo/, 
but it didnt worked for me.